# Transparent pixels aren't transparent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Let me start off by saying I tried to research this, but I'm unable to word it to where I wouldn't get irrelevant results.

So here's the issue. I have a button (actually, 6 buttons) which have a rounded corner appearance. They're saved as PNGs, and loaded into the button using button.BackgroundImage = [resource]. Five of them work perfectly fine. When they're clicked, the background image is changed and, again, looks fine - including changing back when the button is no longer pressed. Then there's the button in the screenshot below.

I have no clue where this green color is coming from - in fact, when I go pixel-by-pixel over the image using GetPixel, and check the ARGB values, they turn out to be purples with A = 0. Also confusing is that the green only shows up at run-time -- as shown in the image. According to PhotoShop and GiMP, the RGB is 46,139,86 .. GetPixel shows them to be various colors in the purple range, but as an example, at 0,0 it shows 164,119,182 A:0.

Here's the list of things I've tried (some pseudocode):

- if (pixel.A == 0) { SetPixel(x,y,Color.Transparent); } -- No change
- if (pixel.A == 0) { SetPixel(x,y,Form1.TransparencyKey); } -- See
  through to desktop instead of form background (as expected).
- Use a known good image (see screenshot) -- No change.
- Delete control, copy and paste a known good control (see screenshot)
  -- No change.
- Add another control, hoping I could hide the flawed one and basically
  just ignore it. -- All new buttons have this issue.
- Move button to different area of form (long story). -- No change.
- Set no background in designer, then set the background in Form1.Load. -- No
  change.
- Restart Visual Studio. -- No change.
- Clean solution, rebuild. -- No change.
- Restart computer. -- No change.

Anyone have this issue before, or know what's going on? I have a solution that works (use a panel as a button - I just tested it and the transparency is fine on a new panel) .. but I'd prefer to figure this out. Thanks in advance!

Here's the imgur:

[image]

Comment: Some real code is going to be necessary to answer this question.

Comment: What would you like to see? I've done absolutely nothing to the button on the bottom right other than copy and paste the control above it, so there would be no code to show that I can think of. The button above has no code associated with it, either.. other than what's in the Designer.cs - which is exactly the same as the button below, with the exception of the name.

Comment: You are going to have to create a minimum repro project, post it to github or a file sharing service.

Comment: Could it be something to do with the button having the focus?